# Neural Network Input

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network

Is this possible to give input to ANN in Non-numeric form, like, *English text sentence* **"Eat an Apple daily"** specially in *Unicode text*, and ANN return output in text form only. Answer Like **"Yes" "No"**.
I don't know much about ANN but all the example codes I studied , like XOR , image input , all deal with Numeric input in ANN.

Can you please suggest some code, or links to webpage having examples related to this.

I need to train ANN for some text sentences which are in Unicode text , but don't know how to deal with text input to NN.

Answer (score 1):

What we do to deal with Text input for ANN is to produce a Vector of word. Like you have a dictionary:

- An
- Apple
- Eat
- Steak
- Zebra

And what you give to the ANN input is: [1, 1, 1, 0, 0] for Eat an apple
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1] for Eat Zebra

You train your network like this and for your output you can just say that a 0 output is "No" and 1 is "Yes".

Be careful, with this solution you will have a input layer very large.

Comment: Thanks for reply ..Thierry ... but by using this approach NN will be cumbersome to manage and in my dictionary i have approx 100000 unique words in Unicode text ... and one thing more can we use ANN for Machine Translation(translating one language to another) .. rather then Statistical Machine Translation(SMT) tools... As i know that ANN used to classify things  .. and in Machine Translation is not a problem of classifications. Is this possible using ANN?

Comment: I can't really help you more than that. I used my method for a classification system. I don't really know for something else.